# Calling an Intent from the adapter maybe by InterationListener

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I was told that it is better to start another activity from the main activity instead of starting it from the adapter and that I should use an InteractionListener to communicate with the adapter and call the intent from the main activity.

Problem is I didn't understand how to implement an InteractionListener.

I tried this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating but I don't know how to initialize the callback.

I tried to do this as I was told but I'm beginner and didnt understand this tutorial, got some errors I couldnt solve.

```
interface OnAdapterInteractionListener {
    fun itemSelected(/Some Parameters Maybe/)
}


class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener?
) :  {
    // set on click listener from item to OnAdapterInteractionListener.itemSelected(/* Maybe Item Argument/)


class MainActivity: Activity(), OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    override fun itemSelected(/ Some Parameters*/ ) {
        startAct....
    }
}
```

I just want to call an activity by clicking on some items of my recycler view.

I really appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers helped. I think they all have some java so that they dont work.

That said i solved the problem by :

in the adapter declaration

````
var ctx: Context? = null
```kotlin

in the listener inside adapter
```kotlin
(ctx as MainActivity).openProject()
```kotlin


in the listener inside adapter
```kotlin
fun openProject() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ProjectActivity::class.java)
        this.startActivity(intent)
    }
```kotlin

Well that solved my problem for now. If you know if doing an InterationListener insted is optimal or something please coment, thx.
````

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a list of names(`String`s) and you want to show them as a list. When one of these names is clicked you should show show clicked item(name) within another *activity*. You can implement it as following.

Your `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Adapter `ItemRecyclerViewAdapter`, subclass of `RecyclerView.Adpater`, which requires *list of Strings* as a constructor argument and which is able to accept `OnAdapterInteractionListener`(**Edit:** Placed inside the adpater) to interact with activity or fragment:

```
class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(private val names: List<String>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var nameClickListener: OnAdapterInteractionListener? = null

    fun setOnAdapterInteractionListener(listener: OnAdapterInteractionListener) {
        nameClickListener = listener
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_name, parent, false)

        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return names.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.tvName.text = names[position]
    }


    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                nameClickListener?.itemSelected(names[adapterPosition], adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnAdapterInteractionListener {

        fun itemSelected(name: String, position: Int)
    }
}
```

And `MainActivity` class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mAdapter: ItemRecyclerViewAdapter
    private val names: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        initNames()
        mAdapter = ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(names)
        mAdapter.setOnAdapterInteractionListener(object : ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.OnAdapterInteractionListener {
            override fun itemSelected(name: String, position: Int) {
                Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailActivity::class.java).also {
                    it.putExtra("name", name)
                    startActivity(it)
                }
            }
        })

        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }

    private fun initNames() {
        names.add("Name1")
        names.add("Name2")
        names.add("Name3")
    }
}
```

Next you should implement `DetailActivity` which handles *StringExtra* as shown bellow and sets it to `TextView`:

```
intent?.getStringExtra("name").also {
    detailText.text = it
}
```

Here `detailText` is a `TextView`.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer ! Where do I put the interface ? in another kotlin file ?

Comment: It is better to put within `ItemRecyclerViewAdapter` bellow `MyViewHolder` inner class. I edited my answer @AndreAndriole

Comment: Im getting unresolved reference with adapter.setOnAdapterInteractionListener in the main activity. but I have it inside the adapter i dont know why unresolved

Comment: Strange that it works on companion object but there i cant "nameClickListener = listener"

Comment: Have you solved the issue, @AndreAndriole? If you have, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark next to it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle item click of an adapter. Refer to detailed answer here [Passing data from one activity to interactor of another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705265/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-interactor-of-another-activity/56705798#56705798)

Especially TaskItemListener usage in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple and straight forward. You have to create an interface to act as the listener and have to implement it in your activity. Then you should pass that implementation / reference to the adapter for accessing the interface method from adapter.

**Sorry that it is in java**. But you can follow the same method

Create and interface. You can create it inside the adapter / as a separate class (I am creating it inside my adapter)

```
public interface AdapterCallback{

        void onAdapterSelected(int pos);

    }
```

And inside the activity.

```
MyAdapter.AdapterCallback callback = new MyAdapter.AdapterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdapterSelected(int pos) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
            SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    };
```

Then pass this implementation to the adapter while creating it.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(dataList, callback); //dataList is list variable name
```

You have to make changes in adapter constructor as well.

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Student> data, AdapterCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.myList = data;
        }
```

Then inside onBindViewHolder, replace the start activity code with callback.onAdapterSelected

```
viewHolder.mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    callback.onAdapterSelected(i);
                }


   });
```